# Unable to get python split() working with £

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, split

I am trying to split a string by '£'. I have tried the following:

```
example = "£2.99£14.99"
example.split("£")
```

and:

```
example = "£2.99£14.99"
example.split("£".encode("utf-8"))
```

and:

```
example = "£2.99£14.99"
example.split("£".encode("utf-8", "ignore"))
```

They all give the following error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file example.py on line 38, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

I am not sure how to proceed. Can someone assist?

Comment: Have you tried reading the link in the error message? What did you find there, and did you have trouble applying the advice?

Comment: @Thefourthbird: then at least use an example site that uses Python 2, not 3, and *use the correct syntax*, which includes making it the first or second line (not the third).

Comment: Instead of declaring the encoding, you could also use `\xc2\xa3` to encode the pound sign as UTF-8 in the string literal.

Comment: I think you should use 'p' instead of the Pound Symbol. 'p' is included in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [**link from your error**](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/):

> Python will default to ASCII as standard encoding if no other encoding hints are given.
>
> To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must be placed into the source files either as first or second line in the file.

---

So **you need to [define your encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#defining-the-encoding)** at the beginning of your `example.py` file.

Exemple, if you want UTF-8 encoding, use the following line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```